# New Linux system for Blender

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, drivers, linux, system

I have just received my new Linux computer, I am coming from MAC background and I am having a few problems.

I have a AMD 3970X with Nvidia 2080Ti with 64Gbs Ram but my system lags and Blender crashes.

I am having better results from CPU cycles rendering than with GPU. When I choose to work with both in the system preferences, Blender crashes all the time, my 2013 old iMac did better than this.

What am I doing wrong? Must I install something in Linux to make it work?
I am using the Arcolinux distro

Comment: Try reading the documentation for common GPU problems and possible solutions on Linux : https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/troubleshooting/gpu/linux/amd.html

Answer (score 2):

**My Answer:**

This sounds at first as if some drivers are not installed in the optimal version or sth is missconfigured.

**My Advice:**

If you are an inexperienced Linux user, you will have a hard time avoiding independent google and building up a certain technical understanding. Part of this is to better isolate your problem than "... my system lags, Blender crashes, etc... [...] blender crashes all the time... My 2013 old Imac did better than this"

Start by familiarizing yourself with your graphics card driver.
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA

When you narrowed down your problem and cant find a way to fix it ask at https://unix.stackexchange.com/

A general hint which is completely at the wrong place here but might help your actual goal: Arcolinux is based on Archlinux. This is advertised as "A simple basic system can be extended almost arbitrarily according to the needs of the respective user". Arch is a powerful tool especially if you want to create a minimalistic operating system for special requirements. There exists distributions where beginner friendliness is a bigger goal than custom experience.

Answer (score 2):

Hello fellow Linux user!

For taking advantage of your Nvidia RTX card, it is recommended to install the non-free Nvidia driver.  I also have an RTX (a smaller one, the 2060) and it works fine with Blender 2.8x, renders in minutes and never crashes.

Comment: Indeed, the default "nouveau" open source drives do not work with blender. You must install the ones from Nvidia.